# MariaDB does not execute queries with high limits

Tags: mysql, mariadb, myisam

I recently switched from MySQL to MariaDB and some queries are not working anymore.

Example:
I've a table with 150.000 rows and execute the following query:

`SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 122000,100`

Sure, that need some seconds, but should work. On MySQL it works properly, but with MariaDB the query loads and loads and nothing happens (the server load increases of course). 
I'm using the same engine (MyISAM) and have no idea how to fix that.
Does anybody know if there is something in the config I could change to make it working?
I'm a bit confused, because it worked with MySQL but doesn't with MariaDB.

Thanks in advance.

Some additional information:

- **SHOW CREATE TABLE posts**

`` CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_hash` binary(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0',
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `search` text CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `forumid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `timecount` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `added` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `poststatus` enum('open','closed') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `likes` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `comments` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `views` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `hits` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `thanks` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `upvotes` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `downvotes` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `last_answer` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `hidden` enum('yes','no') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `userid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `last_edit` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `username` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `extralink` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `editreason` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_vote` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `style` enum('legacy','modern','default') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default',
  `genre` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_thanks` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `last_reply_username` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `approved_at` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `start` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `end` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `thread_status` enum('default','removed','awaiting') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default',
  `refered_by` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cid` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
  `options` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 1,
  `rating` float(3,1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_hash` (`user_hash`),
  UNIQUE KEY `title` (`title`),
  KEY `username` (`username`),
  KEY `visible` (`visible`),
  KEY `added` (`added`),
  KEY `upvotes` (`upvotes`),
  KEY `downvotes` (`downvotes`),
  KEY `last_answer` (`last_answer`),
  KEY `likes` (`likes`),
  KEY `comments` (`comments`),
  KEY `thanks` (`thanks`),
  KEY `hits` (`hits`),
  KEY `last_reply_username` (`last_reply_username`),
  KEY `last_thanks` (`last_thanks`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `refered_by` (`refered_by`),
  KEY `browse_index` (`forumid`,`hidden`,`style`),
  KEY `forumid` (`forumid`),
  KEY `style` (`style`),
  KEY `last_vote` (`last_vote`),
  KEY `hidden` (`hidden`,`style`),
  KEY `cid` (`cid`),
  KEY `options` (`options`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `search` (`search`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `genre` (`genre`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `tags` (`tags`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=610700 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ``

- **SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'posts'**

`{
    "data":
    [
        {
            "Name": "posts",
            "Engine": "MyISAM",
            "Version": 10,
            "Row_format": "Dynamic",
            "Rows": 146228,
            "Avg_row_length": 251,
            "Data_length": 36803536,
            "Max_data_length": 281474976710655,
            "Index_length": 80322560,
            "Data_free": 0,
            "Auto_increment": 610707,
            "Create_time": "2018-11-08 00:21:32",
            "Update_time": "2018-11-09 00:46:14",
            "Check_time": "2018-11-08 00:27:52",
            "Collation": "utf8_unicode_ci",
            "Checksum": null,
            "Create_options": "",
            "Comment": "",
            "Max_index_length": 288230376151710720,
            "Temporary": "N"
        }
    ]
}`

- What client is issuing the query?

  - I tried different clients. The issue has nothing to do with the client.
- Which version of MariaDB?

  - 10.3.10

Comment: Can you try this [sentence](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=827d4d18463308df482300a97157d0db)?.

Comment: When you use `LIMIT` you should also use an `ORDER BY` statement, otherwise it's not clear which rows you get.

Comment: @Progman: Here new [sentence](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=3065d9c3338a104e87d7cec7bf466c59).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I checked out the latest mariadb version from their GIT and updated it. Now it works without any config changes. Looks like there was a bug in 10.3.10.